# How to handle POST request in client-side Blazor WASM application?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have Blazor WASM + Minimal API application, also there's 3-rd party service for authentication. After login this service will redirect to specified url and post user's information in SAML format. Authentication between front and back carried out through JWT token.

I want client-side to receive user's information from authentication service, post it to backend and receive JWT token. But how can I receive POST request from authentication service on frontend?